# Trouble with 802.11ac from a WLE900VX card (QCA9880 ath10k) via hostapd

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, access-point, hostapd

I think this is where I am going wrong-- But I am not sure if it really is the problem and even if it is, I am not sure what to do about it.

> **nl80211: Could not configure driver mode**
>
> nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp6s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
>
> nl80211: Remove monitor interface: refcount=0
>
> nl80211: Remove beacon (ifindex=8)
>
> netlink: Operstate: ifindex=8 linkmode=0 (kernel-control), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
>
> **nl80211 driver initialization failed.**

I've sort of ruled out that it doesn't physically work by using a much less optimal configuration-- I saw it come up in the list of available internet connections on my laptop and connected-- at wireless g speed of 54mbps. I wish I would have made a .bak file of that config, but I didn't. Even if I did, I'm playing with 802.11ac hardware because I want it to go faster.

Yes, I could buy something off the shelf and it would be great. Networking isn't in my core skill set. Building an x86 based router has been a nice distraction from the demands of life, a hobby, and it is fun for the most part. But, I'm stuck again and I'm not sure how to proceed this time.

I'll post a ton of stuff you probably don't even need below... I am happy to post anything else that would help you help me. I appreciate you just taking the time to read my problem. Thanks again.

This is the outcome of starting the hostapd service with the wlp6s0.conf file that gives the particulars for the WLE900VX 802.11ac card:

```
root@gate:/etc/hostapd# service hostapd stop && echo "==================================================================" && hostapd -dddddB /etc/hostapd/wlp6s0.conf

==================================================================
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/wlp6s0.conf
ctrl_interface_group=0
rfkill: initial event: idx=0 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
rfkill: initial event: idx=1 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:6
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: interface wlp6s0 in phy phy0
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 8 iftype 3 (AP)
nl80211: Setup AP(wlp6s0) - device_ap_sme=0 use_monitor=0
nl80211: Subscribe to mgmt frames with AP handle 0x558ab92af100
nl80211: Register frame type=0xb0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_AUTH) 
nl_handle=0x558ab92af100 match=
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=176): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=0): [NULL]
nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp6s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
nl80211: Remove monitor interface: refcount=0
nl80211: Remove beacon (ifindex=8)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=8 linkmode=0 (kernel-control), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
hostapd_interface_deinit_free(0x558ab92ae710)
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: num_bss=1 conf->num_bss=1
hostapd_interface_deinit(0x558ab92ae710)
wlp6s0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
hostapd_bss_deinit: deinit bss wlp6s0
wlp6s0: AP-DISABLED 
hostapd_cleanup(hapd=0x558ab92af900 (wlp6s0))
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlp6s0 wasn't started
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: driver=(nil) drv_priv=(nil) -> 
hapd_deinit
hostapd_interface_free(0x558ab92ae710)
hostapd_interface_free: free hapd 0x558ab92af900
hostapd_cleanup_iface(0x558ab92ae710)
hostapd_cleanup_iface_partial(0x558ab92ae710)
hostapd_cleanup_iface: free iface=0x558ab92ae710
```

I have some interfaces defined here:

```
root@gate:/etc/network# tail -n1000 interfaces

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules

# The primary network interface
auto enp7s0
iface enp7s0 inet dhcp

# Wireless interfaces
auto wlp1s0
iface wlp1s0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.220
  netmask 255.255.255.0

auto wlp6s0
iface wlp6s0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.230
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Here is the output of ifconfig:

```
root@gate:/etc/hostapd# ifconfig

enp7s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.103  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::d250:99ff:fe5c:3a18  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether d0:50:99:5c:3a:18  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 8900  bytes 7106294 (6.7 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1484  bytes 183661 (179.3 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.220  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    ether e4:ce:8f:52:2a:23  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp6s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.230  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::6f0:21ff:fe18:4a2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 04:f0:21:18:04:a2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 12  bytes 1144 (1.1 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I think my hostapd.conf flavored wlp6s0.conf file is relevant:

```
root@gate:/etc/hostapd# tail -n1000 wlp6s0.conf

interface=wlp6s0
driver=nl80211
hw_mode=a
channel=0
ssid=q2900mac

auth_algs=1

wmm_enabled=1

ieee80211d=1
country_code=US

wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
rsn_pairwise=TKIP
wpa_passphrase=password

ieee80211n=1

ht_capab=[HT40+][SHORT-GI-40][TX-STBC][RX-STBC1][DSSS_CK-40][LDPC][MAX-AMSDU-3839]

ieee80211ac=1

vht_capab=[MAX-MPDU-11454][RXLDPC][SHORT-GI-80][TX-STBC-2BY1][RX-STBC-1][MAX-A-MPDU-LEN-EXP7][TX-ANTENNA-PATTERN][RX-ANTENNA-PATTERN]
vht_oper_chwidth=1
vht_oper_centr_freq_seg0_idx=42


ctrl_interface=/var/run/wlp6s0
ctrl_interface_group=0
```

That kind of goes along with the info from iw list:

```
root@gate:/etc/hostapd# iw list

Wiphy phy0
    max # scan SSIDs: 16
    max scan IEs length: 195 bytes
    max # sched scan SSIDs: 0
    max # match sets: 0
    max # scan plans: 1
    max scan plan interval: -1
    max scan plan iterations: 0
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Device supports RSN-IBSS.
    Device supports AP-side u-APSD.
    Supported Ciphers:
            * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
            * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
            * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
            * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
            * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
    Available Antennas: TX 0x7 RX 0x7
    Configured Antennas: TX 0x7 RX 0x7
    Supported interface modes:
             * managed
             * AP
             * AP/VLAN
             * monitor
             * mesh point
    Band 1:
            Capabilities: 0x19ef
                    RX LDPC
                    HT20/HT40
                    SM Power Save disabled
                    RX HT20 SGI
                    RX HT40 SGI
                    TX STBC
                    RX STBC 1-stream
                    Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
                    DSSS/CCK HT40
            Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
            Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
            HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-23
            Bitrates (non-HT):
                    * 1.0 Mbps
                    * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                    * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                    * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                    * 6.0 Mbps
                    * 9.0 Mbps
                    * 12.0 Mbps
                    * 18.0 Mbps
                    * 24.0 Mbps
                    * 36.0 Mbps
                    * 48.0 Mbps
                    * 54.0 Mbps
            Frequencies:
                    * 2412 MHz [1] (30.0 dBm)
                    * 2417 MHz [2] (30.0 dBm)
                    * 2422 MHz [3] (30.0 dBm)
                    * 2427 MHz [4] (30.0 dBm)
                    * 2432 MHz [5] (30.0 dBm)
                    * 2437 MHz [6] (30.0 dBm)
                    * 2442 MHz [7] (30.0 dBm)
                    * 2447 MHz [8] (30.0 dBm)
                    * 2452 MHz [9] (30.0 dBm)
                    * 2457 MHz [10] (30.0 dBm)
                    * 2462 MHz [11] (30.0 dBm)
                    * 2467 MHz [12] (disabled)
                    * 2472 MHz [13] (disabled)
                    * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
    Band 2:
            Capabilities: 0x19ef
                    RX LDPC
                    HT20/HT40
                    SM Power Save disabled
                    RX HT20 SGI
                    RX HT40 SGI
                    TX STBC
                    RX STBC 1-stream
                    Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
                    DSSS/CCK HT40
            Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
            Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
            HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-23
            VHT Capabilities (0x338001b2):
                    Max MPDU length: 11454
                    Supported Channel Width: neither 160 nor 80+80
                    RX LDPC
                    short GI (80 MHz)
                    TX STBC
                    RX antenna pattern consistency
                    TX antenna pattern consistency
            VHT RX MCS set:
                    1 streams: MCS 0-9
                    2 streams: MCS 0-9
                    3 streams: MCS 0-9
                    4 streams: not supported
                    5 streams: not supported
                    6 streams: not supported
                    7 streams: not supported
                    8 streams: not supported
            VHT RX highest supported: 0 Mbps
            VHT TX MCS set:
                    1 streams: MCS 0-9
                    2 streams: MCS 0-9
                    3 streams: MCS 0-9
                    4 streams: not supported
                    5 streams: not supported
                    6 streams: not supported
                    7 streams: not supported
                    8 streams: not supported
            VHT TX highest supported: 0 Mbps
            Bitrates (non-HT):
                    * 6.0 Mbps
                    * 9.0 Mbps
                    * 12.0 Mbps
                    * 18.0 Mbps
                    * 24.0 Mbps
                    * 36.0 Mbps
                    * 48.0 Mbps
                    * 54.0 Mbps
            Frequencies:
                    * 5180 MHz [36] (23.0 dBm)
                    * 5200 MHz [40] (23.0 dBm)
                    * 5220 MHz [44] (23.0 dBm)
                    * 5240 MHz [48] (23.0 dBm)
                    * 5260 MHz [52] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                    * 5280 MHz [56] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                    * 5300 MHz [60] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                    * 5320 MHz [64] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                    * 5500 MHz [100] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                    * 5520 MHz [104] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                    * 5540 MHz [108] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                    * 5560 MHz [112] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                    * 5580 MHz [116] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                    * 5600 MHz [120] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                    * 5620 MHz [124] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                    * 5640 MHz [128] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                    * 5660 MHz [132] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                    * 5680 MHz [136] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                    * 5700 MHz [140] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                    * 5720 MHz [144] (23.0 dBm) (radar detection)
                    * 5745 MHz [149] (30.0 dBm)
                    * 5765 MHz [153] (30.0 dBm)
                    * 5785 MHz [157] (30.0 dBm)
                    * 5805 MHz [161] (30.0 dBm)
                    * 5825 MHz [165] (30.0 dBm)
    Supported commands:
             * new_interface
             * set_interface
             * new_key
             * start_ap
             * new_station
             * new_mpath
             * set_mesh_config
             * set_bss
             * authenticate
             * associate
             * deauthenticate
             * disassociate
             * join_ibss
             * join_mesh
             * remain_on_channel
             * set_tx_bitrate_mask
             * frame
             * frame_wait_cancel
             * set_wiphy_netns
             * set_channel
             * set_wds_peer
             * probe_client
             * set_noack_map
             * register_beacons
             * start_p2p_device
             * set_mcast_rate
             * channel_switch
             * set_qos_map
             * connect
             * disconnect
    Supported TX frame types:
             * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
             * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
             * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
             * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
             * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
             * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
             * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
             * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
    Supported RX frame types:
             * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
             * managed: 0x40 0xd0
             * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
             * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
             * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
             * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
             * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
             * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
    software interface modes (can always be added):
             * AP/VLAN
             * monitor
    valid interface combinations:
             * #{ AP, mesh point } <= 8, #{ managed } <= 1,
               total <= 8, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match
    HT Capability overrides:
             * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
             * maximum A-MSDU length
             * supported channel width
             * short GI for 40 MHz
             * max A-MPDU length exponent
             * min MPDU start spacing
    Device supports TX status socket option.
    Device supports HT-IBSS.
    Device supports SAE with AUTHENTICATE command
    Device supports scan flush.
    Device supports AP scan.
    Device supports per-vif TX power setting
    Driver supports full state transitions for AP/GO clients
    Driver supports a userspace MPM
    Driver/device bandwidth changes during BSS lifetime (AP/GO mode)
    Device supports static SMPS
    Device supports configuring vdev MAC-addr on create.
    Device supports VHT-IBSS.
Wiphy phy1
    max # scan SSIDs: 4
    max scan IEs length: 2257 bytes
    max # sched scan SSIDs: 0
    max # match sets: 0
    max # scan plans: 1
    max scan plan interval: -1
    max scan plan iterations: 0
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Device supports RSN-IBSS.
    Device supports AP-side u-APSD.
    Device supports T-DLS.
    Supported Ciphers:
            * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
            * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
            * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
            * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
            * CCMP-256 (00-0f-ac:10)
            * GCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:8)
            * GCMP-256 (00-0f-ac:9)
            * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
            * CMAC-256 (00-0f-ac:13)
            * GMAC-128 (00-0f-ac:11)
            * GMAC-256 (00-0f-ac:12)
    Available Antennas: TX 0x7 RX 0x7
    Configured Antennas: TX 0x7 RX 0x7
    Supported interface modes:
             * IBSS
             * managed
             * AP
             * AP/VLAN
             * WDS
             * monitor
             * mesh point
             * P2P-client
             * P2P-GO
             * outside context of a BSS
    Band 1:
            Capabilities: 0x11ef
                    RX LDPC
                    HT20/HT40
                    SM Power Save disabled
                    RX HT20 SGI
                    RX HT40 SGI
                    TX STBC
                    RX STBC 1-stream
                    Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
                    DSSS/CCK HT40
            Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
            Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
            HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-23
            Bitrates (non-HT):
                    * 1.0 Mbps
                    * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                    * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                    * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                    * 6.0 Mbps
                    * 9.0 Mbps
                    * 12.0 Mbps
                    * 18.0 Mbps
                    * 24.0 Mbps
                    * 36.0 Mbps
                    * 48.0 Mbps
                    * 54.0 Mbps
            Frequencies:
                    * 2412 MHz [1] (15.0 dBm)
                    * 2417 MHz [2] (15.0 dBm)
                    * 2422 MHz [3] (15.0 dBm)
                    * 2427 MHz [4] (15.0 dBm)
                    * 2432 MHz [5] (15.0 dBm)
                    * 2437 MHz [6] (15.0 dBm)
                    * 2442 MHz [7] (15.0 dBm)
                    * 2447 MHz [8] (15.0 dBm)
                    * 2452 MHz [9] (15.0 dBm)
                    * 2457 MHz [10] (15.0 dBm)
                    * 2462 MHz [11] (15.0 dBm)
                    * 2467 MHz [12] (disabled)
                    * 2472 MHz [13] (disabled)
                    * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
    Band 2:
            Capabilities: 0x11ef
                    RX LDPC
                    HT20/HT40
                    SM Power Save disabled
                    RX HT20 SGI
                    RX HT40 SGI
                    TX STBC
                    RX STBC 1-stream
                    Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
                    DSSS/CCK HT40
            Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
            Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
            HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-23
            Bitrates (non-HT):
                    * 6.0 Mbps
                    * 9.0 Mbps
                    * 12.0 Mbps
                    * 18.0 Mbps
                    * 24.0 Mbps
                    * 36.0 Mbps
                    * 48.0 Mbps
                    * 54.0 Mbps
            Frequencies:
                    * 5180 MHz [36] (15.0 dBm)
                    * 5200 MHz [40] (15.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 5220 MHz [44] (15.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 5240 MHz [48] (15.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 5260 MHz [52] (16.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                    * 5280 MHz [56] (16.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                    * 5300 MHz [60] (16.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                    * 5320 MHz [64] (16.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                    * 5500 MHz [100] (disabled)
                    * 5520 MHz [104] (disabled)
                    * 5540 MHz [108] (disabled)
                    * 5560 MHz [112] (disabled)
                    * 5580 MHz [116] (disabled)
                    * 5600 MHz [120] (disabled)
                    * 5620 MHz [124] (disabled)
                    * 5640 MHz [128] (disabled)
                    * 5660 MHz [132] (disabled)
                    * 5680 MHz [136] (disabled)
                    * 5700 MHz [140] (disabled)
                    * 5745 MHz [149] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 5765 MHz [153] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 5785 MHz [157] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 5805 MHz [161] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 5825 MHz [165] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
    Supported commands:
             * new_interface
             * set_interface
             * new_key
             * start_ap
             * new_station
             * new_mpath
             * set_mesh_config
             * set_bss
             * authenticate
             * associate
             * deauthenticate
             * disassociate
             * join_ibss
             * join_mesh
             * remain_on_channel
             * set_tx_bitrate_mask
             * frame
             * frame_wait_cancel
             * set_wiphy_netns
             * set_channel
             * set_wds_peer
             * tdls_mgmt
             * tdls_oper
             * probe_client
             * set_noack_map
             * register_beacons
             * start_p2p_device
             * set_mcast_rate
             * channel_switch
             * set_qos_map
             * connect
             * disconnect
    Supported TX frame types:
             * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
             * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
             * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
             * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
             * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
             * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
             * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
             * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
    Supported RX frame types:
             * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
             * managed: 0x40 0xd0
             * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
             * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
             * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
             * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
             * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
             * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
    software interface modes (can always be added):
             * AP/VLAN
             * monitor
    valid interface combinations:
             * #{ managed } <= 2048, #{ AP, mesh point } <= 8, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
               total <= 2048, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match
             * #{ WDS } <= 2048,
               total <= 2048, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match
    HT Capability overrides:
             * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
             * maximum A-MSDU length
             * supported channel width
             * short GI for 40 MHz
             * max A-MPDU length exponent
             * min MPDU start spacing
    Device supports TX status socket option.
    Device supports HT-IBSS.
    Device supports SAE with AUTHENTICATE command
    Device supports low priority scan.
    Device supports scan flush.
    Device supports AP scan.
    Device supports per-vif TX power setting
    P2P GO supports CT window setting
    Driver supports full state transitions for AP/GO clients
    Driver supports a userspace MPM
    Device supports active monitor (which will ACK incoming frames)
    Driver/device bandwidth changes during BSS lifetime (AP/GO mode)
    Device supports configuring vdev MAC-addr on create.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the next poor sap that happens along...

This is my hostapd.conf file for the XB140 reference board based Compex WLE900VX QCA9880 card:

```
interface=wlp6s0
driver=nl80211
hw_mode=a
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wlp6s0
ctrl_interface_group=0
max_num_sta=255

#logger_syslog=-1
#logger_syslog_level=2
#logger_stdout=-1
#logger_stdout_level=2

#Details for Connecting Clients via WPA2 TKIP
ssid=q2900mAC
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=password

#802.11d Regulatory Restrictions Designations for Which Frequencies and Channels are Legal
ieee80211d=1
country_code=US

#802.11n Configurations
ieee80211n=1
ht_capab=[LDPC][HT40+][SHORT-GI-20][SHORT-GI-40][TX-STBC][DSSS_CCK-40]

#802.11ac Configurations
ieee80211ac=1
vht_capab=[SHORT-GI-80][MAX-MPDU-11454][RXLDPC][TX-STBC-2BY1][MAX-A-MPDU-LEN-EXP3][RX-ANTENNA-PATTERN][TX-ANTENNA-PATTERN]
vht_oper_chwidth=1

#How Many Units of Time Between Beacon Transmissions
beacon_int=100
#Multiplier of How Many Units of Time Between Beacon Transmissions  
dtim_period=2
#(e.g. 100 milliseconds(ms) * 2 = 200 ms between beacons)

#Something About WMM Clients Needing this
wmm_enabled=1

###To Be Completely Honest-- I'm Not Entirely Certain What the Rest of this file does

#QoS Type of Traffic Management Based on Traffic Type

#Background
wmm_ac_bk_cwmin=4
wmm_ac_bk_cwmax=10
wmm_ac_bk_aifs=7
wmm_ac_bk_txop_limit=0
wmm_ac_bk_acm=0

#Best Effort
wmm_ac_be_aifs=3
wmm_ac_be_cwmin=4
wmm_ac_be_cwmax=10
wmm_ac_be_txop_limit=0
wmm_ac_be_acm=0

#Video
wmm_ac_vi_aifs=2
wmm_ac_vi_cwmin=3
wmm_ac_vi_cwmax=4
wmm_ac_vi_txop_limit=94
wmm_ac_vi_acm=0

#Voice
wmm_ac_vo_aifs=2
wmm_ac_vo_cwmin=2
wmm_ac_vo_cwmax=3
wmm_ac_vo_txop_limit=47
wmm_ac_vo_acm=0
```

Also, if you are stuck at 54Mbps-- 802.11g speeds --I needed to **install the wpa_supplicant package**. My Samsung Note8 connects at 650Mbps with this configuration. I have not yet measured actual throughput.

Last but not least, this answer would never have happened without the selfless heroes over at http://lists.infradead.org/mailman/listinfo/hostap

Dank je JC! Additional advice that was passed to me: the Compex WLE1216v5-20 MIMO x 4 card is better... https://www.compex.com.sg/product/wle1216v5-20/ (I cannot confirm just yet, but for what it is worth.)

Answer (score 0):

This is "an answer". It is wrong--but, I ran up above the 30,000 character limit trying to add it to the question above.

The following basic configuration "works"; I can see the wifi network and connect:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=ath10k
hw_mode=a
channel=36
ieee80211n=0
ieee80211ac=0
```

The resulting output looks like this:

```
root@gate:/etc/hostapd# service hostapd stop && echo "==================================================================" && hostapd -dddddB /etc/hostapd/basic.conf

==================================================================
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/basic.conf
rfkill: initial event: idx=0 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
rfkill: initial event: idx=1 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:6
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: interface wlp6s0 in phy phy0
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 8 iftype 3 (AP)
nl80211: Failed to set interface 8 to mode 3: -16 (Device or resource busy)
nl80211: Try mode change after setting interface down
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 8 iftype 3 (AP)
nl80211: Mode change succeeded while interface is down
nl80211: Setup AP(wlp6s0) - device_ap_sme=0 use_monitor=0
nl80211: Subscribe to mgmt frames with AP handle 0x558199f770c0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xb0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_AUTH) nl_handle=0x558199f770c0 match=
nl80211: Register frame type=0x0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ASSOC_REQ) nl_handle=0x558199f770c0 match=
nl80211: Register frame type=0x20 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_REASSOC_REQ) nl_handle=0x558199f770c0 match=
nl80211: Register frame type=0xa0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_DISASSOC) nl_handle=0x558199f770c0 match=
nl80211: Register frame type=0xc0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_DEAUTH) nl_handle=0x558199f770c0 match=
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x558199f770c0 match=
nl80211: Register frame type=0x40 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_PROBE_REQ) nl_handle=0x558199f770c0 match=
nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 8
nl80211: if_indices[16]: 8
phy: phy0
BSS count 1, BSSID mask 00:00:00:00:00:00 (0 bits)
nl80211: Regulatory information - country=US (DFS-FCC)
nl80211: 2402-2472 @ 40 MHz 30 mBm
nl80211: 5170-5250 @ 80 MHz 23 mBm
nl80211: 5250-5330 @ 80 MHz 23 mBm (DFS)
nl80211: 5490-5730 @ 160 MHz 23 mBm (DFS)
nl80211: 5735-5835 @ 80 MHz 30 mBm
nl80211: 57240-63720 @ 2160 MHz 40 mBm
nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=36 freq=5180 MHz max_tx_power=23 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=40 freq=5200 MHz max_tx_power=23 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=44 freq=5220 MHz max_tx_power=23 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=48 freq=5240 MHz max_tx_power=23 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=149 freq=5745 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=153 freq=5765 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=157 freq=5785 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=161 freq=5805 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=165 freq=5825 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Completing interface initialization
Mode: IEEE 802.11a  Channel: 36  Frequency: 5180 MHz
DFS 0 channels required radar detection
nl80211: Set freq 5180 (ht_enabled=0, vht_enabled=0, bandwidth=20 MHz, cf1=5180 MHz, cf2=0 MHz)
  * freq=5180
  * vht_enabled=0
  * ht_enabled=0
RATE[0] rate=60 flags=0x1
RATE[1] rate=90 flags=0x0
RATE[2] rate=120 flags=0x1
RATE[3] rate=180 flags=0x0
RATE[4] rate=240 flags=0x1
RATE[5] rate=360 flags=0x0
RATE[6] rate=480 flags=0x0
RATE[7] rate=540 flags=0x0
hostapd_setup_bss(hapd=0x558199f77900 (wlp6s0), first=1)
wlp6s0: Flushing old station entries
nl80211: flush -> DEL_STATION wlp6s0 (all)
wlp6s0: Deauthenticate all stations
nl80211: send_mlme - da= ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff noack=0 freq=0 no_cck=0 offchanok=0 wait_time=0 fc=0xc0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_DEAUTH) nlmode=3
nl80211: send_mlme -> send_frame
nl80211: send_frame - Use bss->freq=5180
nl80211: send_frame -> send_frame_cmd
nl80211: CMD_FRAME freq=5180 wait=0 no_cck=0 no_ack=0 offchanok=0
CMD_FRAME - hexdump(len=26): c0 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 04 f0 21 18 04 a2 04 f0 21 18 04 a2 00 00 02 00
nl80211: Frame command failed: ret=-16 (Device or resource busy) (freq=5180 wait=0)
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=8 (wlp6s0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=8 (wlp6s0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=8 (wlp6s0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=8 (wlp6s0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
Using interface wlp6s0 with hwaddr 04:f0:21:18:04:a2 and ssid "ath10k"
nl80211: Set beacon (beacon_set=0)
nl80211: Beacon head - hexdump(len=57): 80 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 04 f0 21 18 04 a2 04 f0 21 18 04 a2 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 00 01 00 00 06 61 74 68 31 30 6b 01 08 8c 12 98 24 b0 48 60 6c 03 01 24
nl80211: Beacon tail - hexdump(len=10): 7f 08 04 00 00 02 00 00 00 40
nl80211: ifindex=8
nl80211: beacon_int=100
nl80211: dtim_period=2
nl80211: ssid - hexdump_ascii(len=6):
     61 74 68 31 30 6b                                 ath10k          
  * beacon_int=100
nl80211: hidden SSID not in use
nl80211: privacy=0
nl80211: auth_algs=0x3
nl80211: wpa_version=0x0
nl80211: key_mgmt_suites=0x4
nl80211: pairwise_ciphers=0x1
nl80211: group_cipher=0x1
nl80211: beacon_ies - hexdump(len=10): 7f 08 04 00 00 02 00 00 00 40
nl80211: proberesp_ies - hexdump(len=10): 7f 08 04 00 00 02 00 00 00 40
nl80211: assocresp_ies - hexdump(len=10): 7f 08 04 00 00 02 00 00 00 40
nl80211: Set wlp6s0 operstate 0->1 (UP)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=8 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
wlp6s0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
wlp6s0: AP-ENABLED 
wlp6s0: Setup of interface done.
ctrl_iface not configured!
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, sports fans-- it seems when you stop hostapd, it isn't enough to release whatever previously registered the authentication frames. This stops my hostapd service start from failing-- so I am going to mark it as the answer.

```
apt install psmisc
killall hostapd

root@gate:/etc/hostapd# service hostapd stop && echo "==================================================================" && hostapd -dddddB /etc/hostapd/wlp6s0.conf
```

Bing, bang, boom I get a connection! ...at 54mbps. So, still not right. Better, functionalish. But, no cigar. Seems to need more cowbell.

Where did you get the hint to do that? I'll tell you. So, I found this mailing list post from 2012:

> On 08/11/2012 07:39 AM, Jouni Malinen wrote:
>
> > On Wed, Jul 11, 2012 at 02:21:40PM -0700, Ben Greear wrote:
> >
> > > Kernel is 3.3.8+, hostapd is from a few days ago.  Any idea
> > >       why this is failing?
> > >
> > > 1342041584.536008: nl80211: Subscribe to mgmt frames with AP handle 0x9a97900
> > >       1342041584.536052: nl80211: Register frame type=0xb0 nl_handle=0x9a97900
> > >       1342041584.536075: nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=0): [NULL]
> > >       1342041584.536177: nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=176): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
> > >       1342041584.536201: nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=0): [NULL]
> > >       1342041584.536263: nl80211: Failed to set interface vap0 into AP mode
> >
> > The driver did not seem to accept the request to register for processing
> >     Authentication frames due to something else had already registered for
> >     those. Did you have some other interfaces running as an AP at the same
> >     time?
>
> Yes, that seemed to be the problem.  I had some stale hostapd processes running.  I'm killing them harder now..and haven't seen any problems
>   lately.
>
> Thanks,
>   Ben